# In defense of our future - Discharge guitar tabs

Tags: guitar, tablature, punk

i was just curious if someone knows this. I've been trying to find tabs for "In defense of our future - Discharge" but the internet seems to have this one really hidden and there's no site where I can find it. I bet is not a hard tab, but still does anyone knows either where to find it and/or why this one's hard to find?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)